# Why does the rollapply function in R returns a matrix when applied to a vector?

Tags: r, function, finance, rollapply

I have a tibble of daily financial data. Similar to the below:

```
head(df)

tibble [2,871 x 2] (S3: tbl_df/tbl/data.frame)
Price | Volatility
15.4    17.5
14.7    17.8
14.4    17.7
14.9    17.8
...     ...
```

I have written a function to calculate z-scores:

```
zscore <- function(x) {
  z <- (x-mean(x))/sd(x)
  return(z)
}
```

I want to add two additional columns, 1) which calculates each row's z-score, and another that calculates the rolling z-scores over a period of 255 business days (i.e. approx. 1 calendar year)

I've written the below code which returns an error message:

```
df %>%
  mutate(full_zscore = zscore(Volatility),
         roll_zscore = rollapply(Volatility, 255, FUN = zscore, align = "right"))

Error: Invalid index: out of bounds
```

Upon further investigation I noticed that the rollapply function returns a `matrix` and hence why i get the error message.

Can anyone help me understand why the `rollapply(df$Volatility, 255, FUN = zscore, alighn = "right")` returns a matrix rather than a rolling z-score on the new variable column?

Thanks!

Comment: Because your `zscore` function returns a vector of the same length as its input.

Comment: I'm unclear what a "rolling z-score" is supposed to be.

Comment: Maybe what you want is: `zscore1 <- function(x) tail((x - mean(x)) / sd(x), 1)`  so that it is returning a scalar rather than vector and 
`rollapplyr(Volatility, 255, zscore1, fill = NA)` Note `r` at the end of `rollapplyr` .

Comment: I think I got it, thanks everyone. In the end the `roll_zscore` column formula needed to be written like this to work: `roll_zscore = (Volatility - rollapplyr(Volatility, 255, mean, fill = NA))/rollapplyr(Volatility, 255, sd, fill = NA)`